# Passing Data between Classes Without Storyboards (Delegation)

Tags: ios, delegates

I'm trying to use a delegate to send data from one class to another.

I set the delegate in this class:

```
class AnswerViewController: UIViewController, tagToIndexDelegate{    
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getDictionary()
}

func getDictionary() {
    let myCell = MyCell()
    myCell.delegate = self
    print(123)
}

func finishPassing(dictionary: Dictionary<Int, Int>) {
    print(dictionary)
}
}
```

And get data via the delegate in this class:

```
protocol tagToIndexDelegate: class {
func finishPassing(dictionary: Dictionary<Int,Int>)
}

class MyCell: UITableViewCell, YSSegmentedControlDelegate{

var delegate: tagToIndexDelegate?

 func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, willPressItemAt      index: Int) {

    tagToIndex[actionButton.tag] = index
    delegate?.finishPassing(dictionary: tagToIndex)

}    
}
```

I haven't been able to get the `dictionary` value to print in the `AnswerViewController` class. `AnswerViewController` is definitely working, because whenever I press the button to segue to this view controller the print statement is executed (the instance of `AnswerViewController` is not created until the button is pressed).

It's worth noting that I am not using storyboards in this project, otherwise I could use the delegate in conjunction with the storyboard segue to complete the task.

Comment: I think you can check by adding a break point before delegate?.finishPassing(dictionary: tagToIndex) to see whether AnswerViewController is properly assigned as delegate , while you are doing  Please check what does tagToIndex contains at this point. Please try and tell the result

Comment: Is `MyCell` supposed to be in a UITableView?  You should set the delegate where you allocate the cell in `cellForRowAt:`

Comment: @Paulw11 I tried that and it actually worked quite well. The problem is that after setting the delegate in `cellForRowAt` the only place I am able to use the stub to access `tagToIndex` is within the `TableViewController` class. That doesn't help me too much considering I need `tagToIndex` in `answerViewController`. I may be missing something fundamental, I'm pretty new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Something is wrong here:

```
func segmentedControl(_ segmentedControl: YSSegmentedControl, willPressItemAt      index: Int) {

    tagToIndex[actionButton.tag] = index
    delegate?.finishPassing(dictionary: tagToIndex)

}
```

You are updating `tagToIndex[actionButton.tag] = index,` but it's not storing back.

Hope this will help!

Comment: This appears to be the problem. Any idea on how I might fix this?